# Unable to override default maven settings in Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide, maven-3

I have maven installed in system with overridden default **m2** folder repository (it moved to another disk from default location) i want to make Idea used this installation instead of maven bundled in Idea itself. But in every time i override this maven settings in Idea it constantly change it to default when i open another project. I change it in Idea Default settings `file -> other settings -> default settings -> maven` and in `file -> settings -> maven` (here constantly changes to default) What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but this worked for me using version Ultimate 2017.3 Preview:

1 Select **File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings**

2 From the list of categories in the **Default Settings** window, select **Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven**.

3 For the input field labeled **Maven home directory**:

- Click its "find" button labelled **"..."** to the right of that field.
- Locate and select the version of Maven that you want to become the default, and click **OK**. The **Maven home directory** field will become populated with your choice:

[image: defaultSettings]

4 Click **OK** to close the **Default Settings** window. That's all, and there's no need to restart IDEA.

To verify the process:

- Create a new Maven project: **File -> New -> Project... -> Maven**....
- Once the project has been created select **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven**.
- The **Maven home directory** field should be populated with the directory you selected as the default in step 3 above.

(I think IDEA's menu entries could be improved. Having **Project Settings** and **System Settings** instead of **Settings** and **Other Settings -> Default Settings** might reduce confusion.)